# Problem with enumeration when importing WSDL to Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, visual-studio-2010, wsdl

I have an enumeration declared in WSDL like this

```
<xsd:simpleType name="KopRate">
        <xsd:annotation>
          <xsd:documentation>Information</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
          <xsd:enumeration value="0" />
          <xsd:enumeration value="13" />
          <xsd:enumeration value="21" />
          <xsd:enumeration value="56" />
          <xsd:enumeration value="ts" />
          <xsd:enumeration value="kp" />
        </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

The problem is Visual Studio generates an enumeration class like this (adding this 'Item' word):

```
namespace TestNmsp
{
    [GeneratedCode("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.1")]
    [XmlType(Namespace = "http://www.kop.com/test/schema")]
    [Serializable]
    public enum KopRate
    {
        [XmlEnum("0")] Item0,
        [XmlEnum("13")] Item13,
        [XmlEnum("21")] Item21,
        [XmlEnum("56")] Item56,
        ts,
        kp,
    }
}
```

Of course I would like to have an enumeration without this 'Item' part. Why this is happening and how can I pass that?

Comment: The 'why' is because C# identifiers can't start with digits. The 'how' I will leave for someone who knows

Comment: Hmm maybe no one knows. Is it actually causing a problem? I guess from the `XmlEnum` attribute that the webservice call actually works OK, it's just you'd like your code to be able to refer to the enum values by their 'real' names?

Answer (score 0):

The reason because the word Item is being added is because the following:

```
public enum KopRate
{
    0,
    13,
    21,
    56,
    ts,
    kp
}
```

Is not valid for C# Syntax. The workaround to keep the WSDL as is an be able to deserialize the possible values is to add a letter or something as a prefix. In this case the "Item" word.

If you have control over the WSDL, It's recommended to change the values of the enumeration in order to respect the naming conventions.

If you do **not** have control over the WSDL. You can always change the enumeration as you want, but keeping the XMLEnum attribute, in order to let the deserialization process work correctly.

e.g.:

```
namespace TestNmsp
{
    [GeneratedCode("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.1")]
    [XmlType(Namespace = "http://www.kop.com/test/schema")]
    [Serializable]
    public enum KopRate
    {
        [XmlEnum("0")] Rate0,
        [XmlEnum("13")] Rate13,
        [XmlEnum("21")] Rate21,
        [XmlEnum("56")] Rate56,
        ts,
        kp,
    }
}
```

Please be aware that if you regenerate the proxy you will lose this change.

Regards,